# Deploy multiple instances of war on Hadoop through Apache Twill

Tags: jetty, hadoop2, apache-twill

I've a web app archive (war) file which is deployed on Tomcat. It contains some REST services. To scale, I want to deploy these REST services (either as war or as jar) on Hadoop cluster through Apache Twill. I want to use `Jetty` instead of `Tomcat`.

I couldn't find something very helpful. I'm looking for something like a detailed technical guide, or even better, a step-by-step guide.